# Is there any advantage to owning physical bitcoins?

Tags: physical-coins

The title pretty much says it all? Is there a security advantage to owning physical bitcoins such as those offered by Casascius? If so is it significant enough to justify the price difference between electronic and physical bitcoins?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a security advantage

Kinda. On one hand, you don't have to worry about getting a virus and losing your coins.

On the other hand, you need to trust that the person who made those physical bitcoins doesn't still have a way to spend them. (They could have saved a copy of the private key for claiming those coins before writing it below the hologram.)

Answer (score 1):

- a good Bitcoin conversation starter prop
- look pretty (Casascius holograms) ;-)